# timeout using TCL

Tags: tcl

Is there a way in TCL to enclose a piece of code in a timeout block? What I mean by that is that the block will exit after a particular timeout even if the execution is not complete.
For instance:-

```
timeout (interval) {
#wait for socket connection here

}
```

If no connection is established in interval time, the block exits.

Thanks and Regards,
Anjali

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anjali,
You are looking for [`vwait`](http://www.hume.com/html84/mann/vwait.html).

Here is an example: Wait five seconds for a connection to a server socket, otherwise close the socket and continue running the script:

```
# Initialise the state
after 5000 set state timeout
set server [socket -server accept 12345]
proc accept {args} {
   global state connectionInfo
   set state accepted
   set connectionInfo $args
}

# Wait for something to happen
vwait state

# Clean up events that could have happened
close $server
after cancel set state timeout

# Do something based on how the vwait finished...
switch $state {
   timeout {
      puts "no connection on port 12345"
   }
   accepted {
      puts "connection: $connectionInfo"
      puts [lindex $connectionInfo 0] "Hello there!"
   }
}
```

**Edit**
You will need to communicate with your UART device using [non blocking I/O](http://www.beedub.com/book/2nd/event.doc.html#1789).

Comment: Hi Byron, thanx for the response. 
I should have been more specific in the question. 
What I actually need to do is send some data over the UART interface to my device under test and sometimes the script hangs while doing this. I need to interrupt the script/block in that such a case. I thought a timeout block will help. Any ideas what else i can do?

Comment: You should be able to adapt the above code to do that. Just add your code to do the UART connection between `after` and `vwait`. Have the results go into state. After the `vwait` close the UART connection. Take a closer look at the above code and it should be clear.

Comment: vwait+after don't solve the generic question proposed. The solution works only in the specific case of Anjali's need, and only if using non-blocking I/O as mentioned by Byron. Check my  question/answer to understand why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096240/tcl-vwait-and-after-not-as-expected
I'm still looking for a way of implementing this, if anyone knows... :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, every few years I keep tripping over the same issues. I want to offer an alternative to `vwait` because, in fact, it is not necessary, though there are a couple of important caveats which have not been pointed out. This is specifically targeting timeouts during serial i/o, as in the original question. It's an excerpt. I know complete code is preferable, but all i/o will be unique to your device, anyway.

```
set port /dev/ttyUSB0
set TIMEOUT 1000

### Important: this MUST be a global variable, even if
### it's only used in this subroutine 
global waitFlag

### for timeouts to work, need non-blocking i/o on the port
if {[catch {open $port "RDWR"} fh]} {
  puts stderr "Cannot open $port"}
  return "error"
  }
fconfigure $fh -mode 38400,n,8,1 -buffering none -blocking 0

### In this example, remote device responds with "<OK>" when
### "<RS>" is sent, though it may take a few read operations
### to get the full string. Your protocol may vary.

puts -nonewline $fh "<RS>"
flush $fh

set waitFlag 1
### create a timeout: after a while, flag will change value
set timeout [after $TIMEOUT {set waitFlag 0}]

set response ""
set n -1
while {$n == -1} {
  ### 10ms delay between successive reads, no point going faster than
  ### your serial i/o. Fine tune for speed and size of packets.
  after 10
  append response [read $fh]
  ### keep reading until the closing ">" arrives ...
  set n [string first > $response]
  ### ... or the waitFlag changes to indicate timeout
  ### Important: without an "update", the delayed change in waitFlag
  ### will not propagate back.
  update
  if { $waitFlag == 0 } {break}
  }
close $fh

### Important: a successful read needs to cancel the pending timeout
### otherwise it may hang around and time out unexpectedly on the next
### communication.
if {$waitFlag == 0} { return "timeout" }\
else                { after cancel $timeout; return $response }
```